# parameter passing with sqlite.execSQL function in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i want use an insert or replace query, here i m giving the code that i have

```
  String sql="insert or replace into Stock_Table values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 

  sqlite.execSQL(sql, new String[]{id,name,code,vat,itmquan,pric});
```

now i want to additionally insert one more field into this table but that field is not string
its a byte array format, i want to add an image into this table, i given the data type for this image as BLOB in table, but i cant able to pass byte array format as a parameter into the above sqlite.execsql func, here i m giving the format that i want to insert

```
byte []byteImage;

String sql="insert or replace into Stock_Table values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 

sqlite.execSQL(sql, new String[]{id,name,code,vat,itmquan,pric,byteImage});
```

how can i make it possible, i cannot able to convert this byte array into string i want to insert image as BLOB format only, please help me to find any solution

Comment: refer this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/550604/Android/Mobile/insert-retreive-image-database

Comment: this link is so bad ... you should not use execSQL for SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE !!! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)

Comment: i already tried like @sunil said, but i could not insert got error, is there any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variant of the [insert method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29), which takes a [ContentValues object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html), which allows you to use a byte array directly:

```java
byte[] byteImage;
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("id", id);
// ...
cv.put("blobcolumn", byteImage);
sqlite.insertWithOnConflict("Stock_Table", null, cv, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

Comment: then wat about the replace option ?

Comment: i cannot able to put CONFLICT_REPLACE in this function.

Answer (score 0):

use this way..

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        SQLiteDatabase myDb;       
         String MySQL;
         int icount;
         byte[] byteImage1 = null;
         byte[] byteImage2 = null;

         MySQL="create table emp1(_id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, fio TEXT not null, picture BLOB);";
           myDb = openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/MyDB.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
      //     myDb.execSQL(MySQL);
          String s=myDb.getPath();
          textView.append("\r\n" + s+"\r\n");       
           myDb.execSQL("delete from emp1");
           ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
           newValues.put("fio", "hello dude");

          /////////// insert picture to blob field ///////////////////// 
          try
          {
          FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/sunil.png"); 
          BufferedInputStream bif = new BufferedInputStream(instream); 
          byteImage1 = new byte[bif.available()]; 
          bif.read(byteImage1); 
          textView.append("\r\n" + byteImage1.length+"\r\n"); 
          newValues.put("picture", byteImage1); 

          long ret = myDb.insert("emp1", null, newValues); 
          if(ret<0) 
         textView.append("\r\n!!! Error add blob filed!!!\r\n");
          } catch (IOException e) 
          {
              textView.append("\r\n!!! Error: " + e+"!!!\r\n");   
          }

        ////////////Read data ////////////////////////////  
        Cursor cur = myDb.query("emp1",null, null, null, null, null, null);
          cur.moveToFirst();
          while (cur.isAfterLast() == false)
          {
              textView.append("\r\n" + cur.getString(1)+"\r\n");
              cur.moveToNext();
          }
        ///////Read data from blob field////////////////////
          cur.moveToFirst();
          byteImage2=cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("picture")); 
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage2, 0, byteImage2.length));
          textView.append("\r\n" + byteImage2.length+"\r\n"); 
        //////////////////////////  
          cur.close();
          myDb.close();

    }
```